Obfuscar 2.2.40 does not write output
Seems that obfuscar does nothing. Or at least doesn't write to output path. I try to run obfuscar manually to obfuscate .net standard 2.0 class library.
Powershell command
& "D:\temp\myApp\packages\Obfuscar.2.2.40\tools\Obfuscar.Console.exe" "D:\temp\myApp\HelloWorld.Application\Obfuscar.xml"

In Output window I get a message saying:
Loading assemblies...Extra framework folders: Done.
Hiding strings...
Renaming:  fields...Parameters...Properties...Events...Methods...Types...Done.
Saving assemblies...Done.
Writing log file...Done.
Completed, 0,74 secs.

Why OutPath stays empty? Where that log file is?
I have following Obfuscar.xml on project root
<Obfuscator>
    <Var name="InPath" value="D:\temp\MyApp\HelloWorld.Application\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0" />
    <Var name="OutPath" value="D:\temp\MyApp\HelloWorld.Application\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\obfuscated" />

    <!-- Obfuscating rules -->
    <Module file="D:\temp\MyApp\HelloWorld.Application\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\HelloWorld.Application.dll">
        <!-- Example of passing type to not be obfuscated -->
        <!--<SkipType name="YourApp.Namespace.PublicType" />-->
    </Module>
    <Var name="KeyContainer" value="VS_KEY_123ABCDEF213456D" />
</Obfuscator>

I have tried also to obfuscate different .exe project and run this as a post-build event.
All projects are signed. I get an error "type 1 or 3 don't remember" until I added keyContainer to configuration.
I don't know what is the problem because obfuscar always returns done without errors.
